# Best way to check for mongoose validation error

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I've got two [validation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) functions for my usermodel

```
User.schema.path('email').validate(function(value, respond) {
  User.findOne({email: value}, function(err, user) {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(user) return respond(false);
    respond(true);
  });
}, 'EMAIL_EXISTS');
```

and the same for `username`

```
User.schema.path('username').validate(function(value, respond) {
  User.findOne({username: value}, function(err, user) {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(user) return respond(false);
    respond(true);
  });
}, 'USERNAME_TAKEN');
```

They return errors in the following format

```
{ message: 'Validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError',
  errors: 
    { username: 
      { message: 'Validator "USERNAME_TAKEN" failed for path username',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        path: 'username',
        type: 'USERNAME_TAKEN' } } }
```

The error for the `email` path is similar. Is there a smarter way to check for those errors than the following?

```
if (err && err.errors && err.errors.username) { ... }
```

This is kind of ugly.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Technically you must check first the error name because not all errors are handled the same way. Then, based on the error name you must check for particular properties, as the errors property that comes with a ValidationError.

Also you put the field name in the error type and this is redundant, it's better to use the same error type because in the error checking procedure you will get the field name also.

So your code can be something like:

```
User.schema.path('email').validate(function(value, respond) {
  User.findOne({email: value}, function(err, user) {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(user) return respond(false);
    respond(true);
  });
}, 'exists');

User.schema.path('username').validate(function(value, respond) {
  User.findOne({username: value}, function(err, user) {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(user) return respond(false);
    respond(true);
  });
}, 'exists');
```

And then, the error checking procedure:

```
if (err) {
  switch (err) {
    case err instanceof mongoose.Error.ValidationError:
      for (field in err.errors) {
        switch (err.errors[field].type) {
          case 'exists':
            ...
            break;
          case 'invalid':
            ...
            break;
          ...
        }
      }
      break;
    default:
      ...
  }
}
```

If you want to shorten this, you have various options. If you only have one type of validation you can do it like this:

```
if (err) {
  if (err instanceof mongoose.Error.ValidationError) {
    for (field in err.errors) {
      ...
    }
  } else {
    // A general error (db, crypto, etc…)
    ...
  }
}
```

The minimal expression of the error check procedure would be similar to what you've wrote in your post:

```
if (err) {
  for (field in err.errors) {
    ...
  }
}
```

This will work because if errors is not defined it will just ignore the for. But you're ignoring all other error types here.

I also think that these error layouts are a bit messing, but don't expect for this to change in a near future.

Comment: ValidationError is generic error and is thrown by several other modules with each having different format and/or properties. Its better to be specific and check `err instanceof mongoose.Error.ValidationError` in your error checking procedure.

Comment: A bit old, but where did you guys find all the error kinds? Can't find it anywhere in the documentation

Answer (score 11):

Just write the following code and enjoy.

```
if (err) {
    console.log('Error Inserting New Data');
    if (err.name == 'ValidationError') {
        for (field in err.errors) {
            console.log(err.errors[field].message); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not something you want everywhere across your code, but it would make a good helper function.

Answer (score 3):

I use AngularJS, so `ngRepeat` displays my validation errors on the web form.  All I need to do is return an array of error messages.

Sometimes Mongoose will throw an error which is NOT a validation error, and in this case the err.errors object will not be present.  I log the execution error.  I still use the same spot on the web form to display the execution error to the user.

```
var makeMongooseErrorMsgArray = function(err){
    var msgArray = [];
    if (err.errors) { // validation errors
        $.each(err.errors, function (key, val) {
            msgArray.push(val.message);
        });
    } else if (err.message){ // should be execution error without err.errors
        errLogr.log(err); // log execution errors
        msgArray.push(err.message);
    } else {
        msgArray.push('Unknown error');
    }
    return msgArray;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By reading all these answers, I consider it's the best to create utility function and reuse it as such:

This is the function that handles `ValidationError` by sending desired response to the client with validation messages, and optionally uses `console.log` to show messages in console.

```
function handleValidationError(err, res, consoleLog = false){
  const messages = []
  for (let field in err.errors) {
    messages.push(err.errors[field].message)
    consoleLog && console.log(err.errors[field].message)
  }
  res.status(422).json({ messages })
}
```

Then in controller where we want to handle error, we check if `err.name` is `ValidationError`, and if so, we use utility function from above.

```
user.save((err) => {
  if (err) {
    if (err.name === 'ValidationError') return handleValidationError(err, res) // here
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error while creating new user' })
  }
  return res.status(201).json({ message: 'User created' })
})
```

Then client would get validation erros in response as such:

```
curl\
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'\
-d '{"email": "foo", "password": "barbaz"}'\
http://localhost:3000/user/new
```

Output:

```
{"messages":["Email validation failure"]}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this helpful which displays all errors in an array.

For example I submitted a form with short password and invalid email.

```
if (err && err.name === 'ValidationError') {
   err.toString().replace('ValidationError: ', '').split(',')
}
```

Which results in this

```
[ 'Please provide a valid email address',
'The password should be at least 6 characters long' ]
```

If you have a comma `,` in your error messages than try without `.split(',')`

No need for `for` loops. Make sure you have validation error messages in your schema. For the above example I have

```
const validateEmail = email => {
  const re = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  return re.test(email);
};

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new Schema({
   ...
   email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: 'Email address is required',
      validate: [validateEmail, 'Please provide a valid email address'],
   },
   password: { type: String, set: encryptPassword, maxlength: [6, 'The password should be at least {MAXLENGTH} characters long'] },
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `validation` method [as described in the API](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-validate)?

```
objectToSave.validate(function(err) {          
  if (err) {
    // handle error
  }     
  else {
    // validation passed
  }
});
```

Comment: `This method is called pre save and if a validation rule is violated, save is aborted and the error is returned to your callback.` So that's basically what I'm already doing. Problem I have is handling the `err` without too much hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Here my unique way to handle mongoose validation error

The code is still in progress once it ready I will update it or you can contribute to extends my code.

```
let message = "";
let title = "Validation Error";
let code = 400;
let requiredFields = [];
for (let field in err.errors) {
    let subMsg = ""
    if (err.errors[field].kind === "required") {
        requiredFields.push(field)
    }
}
if (requiredFields.length > 0) {
    message = "Following fields are required: " + requiredFields.join(", ");
} else {
    message = "Unknown";
}
res.status(code).json({
    status: code,
    message: message,
    title: title
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Approach #1**

My Best Guess for this approach is to use generalized validator with promise based returns,
hope it may help down the road

```
function validateDoc(model,fieldName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    model.validate(err => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err.errors[fieldName]);
      } else {
        return resolve(model);
      }
    });
  })
}

// Access error message in catch() or get the validated doc in then()

validateDoc(model,fieldName)
           .then((model) => console.log(model))
           .catch((message) => console.warn(message))
```

**Approach #2**

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type:String,
    required:[true,'Name is required.'],
    validate:{
      validator:(name) => { name.length <= 2 }
      message:'Name must be longer than two characters'
    }
  }
})
const User = mongoose.model('user',userSchema)
```

Use the **validate:Object** inside schema with **validator:function** and **message:String**

Later when u will try to save the record it will thow the validation error object in the catch function

For Example

```
const newUser = new User({ name: undefined });

newUser.save().catch( ( { errors } ) => { 

let errorBag = [];

Object.keys(errors).forEach((fieldName) => {

errorBag.push({ [fieldName]:errors[fieldName].message })

});

 // All the errors with the **fieldName** and  **errorMessages** 

console.log(errorBag);  

   })
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: violating the constraint returns an E11000 error from MongoDB when saving, not a Mongoose validation error.

```js
try {
  question.options.push(req.body.optiontext);
  await question.save();
  res.json(question);
} catch (err) {
  res.json({ message: "cannot add more than 4 options to a polling question" });
}
```

Comment: tough the context of usage was different; hope this helps;